# Can magento connect and read in real time from another database that the structure is not the same?

Tags: database, magento, import, external

This is my new project and don't know if is possible. My client has another store with its database of 200.000 products. The database structure is not the same as magento use for handling products but sure it has SKU, product name, color, sizes ect...

What i want to know is if is possible to connect with this database, read from that and make magento understand these tables.

I really appreciate if any of professional guys can help me to know if is possible or not and what tool should is use to make that happen?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. Yes you can connect to the db assuming that magento support that db, but magento will not be able to read or write to that db product table because the db table structure, name and schema are different.

You will need to import all your product into magento

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. What about this method called SOAP or API(Webservice)? Just to make sure that there is no way to make my project work. Once again thank you.

Comment: Magento would have to be up and run to use the soap/webservice api hence all the product would have to be loaded in magento

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish, if they have another store why do they want to use magento and that store together?

Comment: Thank you R.S. Is not a store is kind of software that manages warehouses and the database is already done is a SQL database with tables and all other staff. They need to read from their database all products and displaying on web and have chose magento because i don't know maybe for CMS purpose and future options. These tables values change and need to be a synch between magento and their database in real time.